# Django file not uploading: ValueError at / The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I created a form with Django forms. I implemented on HTML page. Everything is ok but my image not uploaded on the database. Also, I set the default image on my DB, but not linked with default image

I was trying to find an issue. I tried `print(request.FILES)` It returned `<MultiValueDict: {}>` I understood my uploaded image didn't upload correctly in my database. Though the form was submitted and when I tried to query from the product model. it will get error `ValueError at /
The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.`

this is my traceback

```py
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 2.2.5
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'product.apps.ProductConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/templates/base.html, error at line 8
   The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
   1 : {% load staticfiles %}
   2 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   3 : <html lang="en">
   4 : <head>
   5 :     <meta charset="UTF-8">
   6 :     <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
   7 :     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   8 :     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcd n.bootstrapcdn.com/ bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   9 : 
   10 : 
   11 : </head>
   12 : <body>
   13 : 
   14 :     <div class="container">
   15 :         <div class="row">
   16 :             <div class="col-md-4">
   17 :                 <a href="{% url 'product:home' %}">Logo</a>
   18 :             </div>


Traceback:

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  829.                     current = current[bit]

During handling of the above exception ('ImageFieldFile' object is not subscriptable), another exception occurred:

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/product/views.py" in product_list
  12.     return render(request, 'product/home.html', context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  209.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  987.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  671.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  796.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  837.                         current = getattr(current, bit)

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in url
  61.         self._require_file()

File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/eShop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in _require_file
  38.             raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

models.py file

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/', default='product.png')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    purchase_price = models.FloatField()
    sales_price = models.FloatField()
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PRODUCT_TYPE)
    measure = models.ForeignKey(Measure, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

forms.py file

```py
class ProductForms(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ))
    image = forms.ImageField(required=False, widget=forms.FileInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ))
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    purchase_price = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    sales_price = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    product_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PRODUCT_TYPE, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    measure = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Measure.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

views.py file

```py
def create_product(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForms(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
        print(request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            product = Product.objects.create(
                user=request.user,
                name=data['name'],
                image=data['image'],
                quantity=data['quantity'],
                purchase_price=data['purchase_price'],
                sales_price=data['sales_price'],
                product_type=data['product_type'],
                measure=data['measure'],
            )

            product.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Form is successfully submitted')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Form is not submitted')
    form = ProductForms()

    return render(request, 'product/product_create.html', {'form': form,})
```

```html
 <form action="" class="was-validated" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

     {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
     <div class="form-group">

          {{ field.label_tag }}
          {{ field }}
     </div>
     {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit Product</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: this error is generated from `return render(request, 'product/home.html', context)` in your `product_list` view. not from this view.

Comment: It error created forms or create view because when I try to upload image. get this ```foo.image.url``` is none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` in the `form` tag, like this

```html
<form action="" class="was-validated" method="post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: works. thanks But I would like to know why I am adding this enctype for this?

Comment: you might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` with your `form` tag.

Your template will be like:

```html
<form action="" class="was-validated" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**HTML forms provide three methods of encoding:**

1. application/x-www-form-urlencoded (the default)
2. multipart/form-data
3. text/plain

We use `multipart/form-data` when the form includes any `<input type="file">` elements.
[To know more..](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp)